# Is a series that contains the index term a function of the same series without the index term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, transformation

Can it be shown that

$U_{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} [i*g(Y_{i})]$

is a function of

$U_{1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} g(Y_{i})$ ?

My intuition tells me that this is not true because of the changing (for lack of a better word) coffecient, $i$, in $U_{2}$. But this is not a sound mathematical explanation.

Any helpful hints about how I can prove or disprove this are greatly appreciated. For example, is there a property of Series or Transformations I can look at to show that this is true or not true?

I have another value

$U_{3} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}[(n-i)g(Y_{i})] = n*\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(Y_{i}) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}[i*g(Y_{i})] = n*U_{1}-U_{2}$

Again, my intuition tells me that $U_{3}$ is a function of $U_{1}$ & $U_{2}$ because $U_{1}$ & $U_{2}$ appear in $U_{3}$. However, what property should I appeal to?

**EDIT:**
For clarification, $g(Y_{i})$ is any constant function, g, of only the $i^{th}$ variable I am considering where $i \in \{1,...,n\}$. Does the specific function, g, matter? For example, is there a an important difference between $g(Y_{i})=Y_{i}$ and $g(Y_{i})=log_{e}(Y_{i})/(c-Y_{i})$ (for some constant c)? Besides the simple algebra of the functions and resulting sereis.

Comment: I do not know what is $g(Y_i)$ but regarding the relation you are considering, I think that you should try the formal power series (over $n$) of your $U_1$ and $U_2$, you will certainly get interesting relation at this level.

Comment: In this case, $g(Y_{i})$ is any function, g, of only the $i^{th}$ variable I am considering where $i \in \{1,...,n\}$. Does the specific function, g, matter? For example, is there a an important difference between $g_{1}(Y_{i})=Y_{i}$ and $g_{2}(Y_{i})=log_{e}(Y_{i})/(c-Y_{i})$ (for some constant c)? Besides the algebra of the functions.

Comment: Well, to be complete about my though, I replace $g(Y_i)$ by $i$ and then your sum $U_1$ is the sum $s_{1,n}$ of integers between $1$ and $n$ as well as $U_2$ is the sum $s_{2,n}$ of the sqare of those integers. In that setting, the good way to understand this is to go through formal power series that is relate $\sum s_{1,n}X^n$ and $\sum s_{2,n}X^n$. For formal power series, Wilf's generatingfunctionology is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U_1(a)=\sum a_i$ and $U_2(a)=\sum ia_i$.

Now consider $a=(a_i)=\begin{cases}1\quad i=1\\0\quad i\neq1\end{cases}$ and $b=(b_i)=\begin{cases}1\quad i=2\\0\quad i\neq2\end{cases}$

$U_1(a)=U_1(b)$ but $U_2(a)\neq U_2(b)$. Thus $U_2$ is not a function of the *individual numbers* produced by $U_1$.